# How can I play a OGG sound file inside of my desktop WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, ogg

I just want a sound to play whenever a user clicks a button. Said sound is in OGG format.

Any help? :D

I tried using MediaPlayer, but that seems to be only for videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt there is native OGG format support in WPF. But you can [find something in the Net](http://www.google.com.ua/search?hl=en&q=ogg+player+C%23&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=)... It looks like this CodeProject article is what you are looking for: [.NET Implementation of an Ogg Vorbis Player](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/OggPlayer.aspx).

Cheers